# How to copy only rows for the selected columns C#?

Tags: datagridview, clone

Copying rows (only cells of rows) of selected columns from datagridview1 to a datagridview2 in c#
So far I done this:

```
int[] onlyCols = { 2,3,5,7 };
int cols = datagridview1.Columns.Count;

datagridview1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect; //default mode
datagridview1.MultiSelect = true;
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) { datagridview1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable; }
datagridview1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
{
    if (onlyCols.Contains(j))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"j={j}");
        datagridview1.Columns[j].Selected = true; 
    } 
}

//then copy the columns that I need to have in datagridview2:
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in datagridview1.SelectedColumns)
{
    datagridview2.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
}
```

Then, lets say, we have 10 columns and 5 rows in datagridview1 and I need to copy only columns from onlyCols(array) into datagridview2 (so far I've done that) but also the cells of the rows for the selected columns.

Comment: The posted code is confusing… instead of looping through `datagridview1` columns once to “select” the columns in the `onlyCols` array, then another loop through those “selected” columns… would it not be easier to simply “clone” the columns that are in the `int` array (`onlyCols`) instead of “selecting” the columns and then cloning the “selected” columns? Example: `foreach (int c in onlyCols) { datagridview2.Columns.Add(datagridview1.Columns[c].Clone() as DataGridViewColumn); }`

Comment: Then to add the rows, the code is going to have to loop through the rows of `dataGridView1` and add those rows to `datagridview2`. Bear in mind that the column indexes will NOT necessarily be the same, therefore you will need to introduce a separate column index variable for `datagridview2`. Example: if the first column cloned in `datagridview1` is column 2, then the index for this column in `datagridview2` is going to be column zero (0). Again, it is difficult to follow exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you can’t get what I described working, I can post a small example. However, I suggest you try this on your own first. Since you have the columns added…I suggest adding the same number of rows in grid1 as empty rows to grid2, then, loop through all the rows in grid1 and copy those columns in the array `onlyCol` to the appropriate columns in grid2. But as I stated previously, the column indexes for each grid will/may be different.

Answer (score 0):

First I like to thank you very much for make me understand this principle of index!
I managed to do what I had in mind to do:

```
datagridview2.Columns.Clear();
datagridview2.Rows.Clear();
foreach (int c in onlyCols) { datagridview2.Columns.Add(datagridview1.Columns[c].Clone() as DataGridViewColumn); }

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in datagridview1.Rows)
{
    int index = datagridview2.Rows.Add();
    int nCell = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)
    {
        if (onlyCols.Contains(o.ColumnIndex))
        {
            datagridview2.Rows[index].Cells[nCell].Value = o.Value;
            nCell++;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: With the guidance of JohnG, I found out that it was do easy to do!
Thanks man!

Comment: Good effort. May I suggest that looping through ALL the columns in each grid1 row with the `foreach` loop… `foreach (DataGridViewCell o in r.Cells)` … may be doing unnecessary work. This is looping through ALL the columns when we are only concerned with the columns in the `onlyCols` variable. I suggest looping again through all the values in the `onlyCols` array. Something like… `foreach (int c in onlyCols) { datagridview2.Rows[index].Cells[nCell++].Value = r.Cells[c].Value;`. This removes the check for the proper column.